# Detect if page is in frame of webcam

Tags: image-processing, opencv, vision

I want to scan some documents and I want to know when a page is "in the frame" of the camera. What I mean by this is the optimal distance from camera to page document (but without cutting any of the document). I want to run the detection program in a loop, so that the user calibrates the camera distance for each document before scanning.

How can I do this?

Comment: This question was already asked here.

Comment: Then can you please provide a link to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply OpenCV findContour on the image to detect the document edges. For this you need to determine an appropriate threshold value which discriminate between background and document.

Then using the contour information, you can tell if the document is touching the limits of the image.